# Gradle build.gradle.kts: how to transform Exec output in a configuration-cache compatible way

Tags: android, git, kotlin, gradle

In a Gradle project (using Gradle 8.5) I use `providers.exec` in order to run `git describe --tags`, so we can generate a nice Android version name. However, the output of this process is changing very often, so always leading to a new App build - and the Gradle configuration cache is also changed. The output is something like `1.0.0-foo-bar-20230101-ea32549d`, but I only want to keep the `1.0.0` part.

This is the code that I have right now:

```
val output = providers.exec { commandLine("git", "describe", "--tags") }
    .standardOutput.asText.get().trim()
    .split('-').first() // get just 1.0.0 part
println(output)
```

This works, but when a Git commit is done (e.g. with `git commit -m 'empty commit' --allow-empty`), the Gradle configuration cache will be invalid:

```
$ ./gradlew help
Calculating task graph as configuration cache cannot be reused because output of the external process 'git' has changed.
…
```

So what happened is: Gradle executed the Git command again and got a different result - e.g. `1.0.0-foo-bar-20230101-12345678` instead of `1.0.0-foo-bar-20230101-ea32549d` - and it therefore invalidated the configuration cache.

Is there a way to transform the standard output before the `exec {}` block ends, in a way that's compatible with the configuration cache?

Thanks a lot!

###### Alternatives considered

- I thought about adding a script `get_version_name_from_git.sh` and using `sed` to get what I want. Unfortunately this won't work on Windows.
- I know there is the Git parameter `--abbrev=0` which will omit the commit hash - but the rest of my tag is still there, and I want to omit that, too.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward solution to your problem is to get rid of an ad hoc implementation in a script via `providers.exec` and instead lift the logic to the standalone task/plugin and make use of new ValueSource API provided by Gradle.

Here is the important part of the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:external_processes):

> A value source implementation is exempt from the automatic detection of work graph cache inputs.
> For example, if the obtain() method calls System.getenv("FOO") then changes to the FOO environment variable only invalidate the cache if the value returned by the obtain() method itself changes. The same applies to reading files or system properties.

You will be able to process the output in the obtain() and avoid configuration cache misses in case the actual input didn't change.

One thing to keep in mind is the fact that since return value of the obtain() is used to check the configuration cache it will be called on every build.

Here is an example of what a value source like this could look like

```
abstract class GitCommandValueSource : ValueSource<String, Parameters> {

    @get:Inject
    abstract val execOperations: ExecOperations

    override fun obtain(): String {
        val output = ByteArrayOutputStream()

        execOperations.exec {
            it.apply {
                commandLine = parameters.commands.get()
                workingDir = parameters.directory.get()
                standardOutput = output
                isIgnoreExitValue = true
            }
        }
        return String(output.toByteArray(), Charset.defaultCharset())
    }
}

interface Parameters : ValueSourceParameters {
    val commands: ListProperty<String>
    val directory: Property<File>
}
```

In your case, instead of just returning the string you could do the processing you want to achieve the required result of making the input stable over commits/tags